# Truncated Response from Nginx server

Tags: json, nginx, postman, kong

I have a .net WebApi service which is hosted on IIS server, it returns JSON response. when i hit the .net service via postman i get proper complete data as expected.
When i call the same service via Kong Api Gateway (Configured on linux machine with Nginx) from postman, i get truncated JSON response from postman and error calling from c# code.

> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

Response from postman as below

[image: Response from Postman]

Can someone please provide me some pointers to proceed with.

Comment: tcpdump on the kong server to check what you have between the different server

Comment: What is the .net version?